# Question about Jean's Equation and Liouville's Theorem

Tags: statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory, phase-space

**TL;DR**

Is this true:
$$\int f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{v})d^3 x d^3 v = \int f(E,L) dE dL \, ?$$

**Intro**

One of the common things that is done in e.g. Binney and Tremaine's book is transforming between $f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{v})$ and $f(E,L)$, where $E$ and $L$ are orbital energy and angular momentum (constants of motion along particle paths).

**Application**

In e.g. [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-902-astrophysics-ii-fall-2004/lecture-notes/lec11.pdf), they use the expression of phase space density $f(E,L)$ to retrieve the density

$$\rho = \int f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{v}) d^3 v = \int J f(E,L) dE dL$$

where $J$ is some Jacobian matrix to relate $d^3v$ and $dE dL$.

However, now it is very unclear to me whether or not both $f(E,L)$ and $f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{v})$ are normalized the same way. Should integrating over all "states" give the same result?

In other words is the following true:

$$\int f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{v})d^3 x d^3 v = \int f(E,L) dE dL $$
or should there be a jacobian as well?

Comment: What are the units of J?  Is it the matrix or its determinant?  If the latter, I am guessing it has units of inverse volume, thus making it appropriate.

Comment: Hi @honeste_vivere ; J is the determinant jacobian

Comment: Then I think that solves the unit issue.

Answer (score 3):

The following expression:
$$
\rho = \int \ f\left(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{v}\right) d^{3}v = \int \ J \ g\left(E,L\right) \ dE \ dL
$$
is okay and consistent with:
$$
\int \ f\left(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{v}\right) \ d^{3}x \ d^{3}v = \int \ g\left(E,L\right) \ dE \ dL
$$
because $J$ is the [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) of the [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant), which means there will be factors of the form $\left(\partial/\partial x_{i} \ \partial/\partial x_{j} \ \partial/\partial x_{k}\right)$ in each term of the determinant.

The units of the $\left(\partial/\partial x_{i} \ \partial/\partial x_{j} \ \partial/\partial x_{k}\right)$ terms are proportional to inverse volume.  The units of $\ f\left(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{v}\right)$ are $\left[ \# \ s^{3} \ m^{-6} \right]$ and the units of $\ g\left(E,L\right)$ are $\left[ \# \ s^{2} \ m^{-3} \ kg^{-1}\right]$.

Therefore, there is nothing wrong with either integral version.  However, as @BobBee pointed out, it should be $\ g\left(E,L\right)$ not $\ f\left(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{v}\right)$ in the $dE \ dL$ integral.

Comment: I see, so you are saying that the two jacobian determinants cancel out?

Comment: But wouldnt the determinant from $d^3v$ contribute as $\frac{\partial E}{\partial v}$?

Comment: I should add that the above form is only valid for non-relativistic cases.  Cancel out?  No, I was showing that the units are okay between the two versions.  I went through this exercise back in grad school and do recall (though vaguely) those two versions.

Comment: I've not calculated this, but whether J has the right units or not, and assuming f in both equations really means f of X and v equal to g of E and L (i.e., different functions of their arguments but the same numerical result of equivalent arguments) and that g is really what you mean on the right side of either equation, the real question is whether J = 1? Otherwise I don't see how the two could be equal. What am I missing if the answer posted is right?

Comment: @BobBee - I see what you mean and yes, you are correct.  The change in the arguments of the function derive from which parameters are a constant of motion.  A similar type of approach is used to model radiation belt particles that are in relatively stable bouncing/drifting/gyrating orbits.