# Distribution function independent of $\boldsymbol\theta$ from Jeans theorem?

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, galaxies, kinetic-theory

In Binney and Tremaine, 2008  2nd ed pg418 the authors state:

> According to the Jeans theorem, the equilibrium DF may depend only on the actions; thus $f_0 =f_0(\mathbf{J})$.

I have problems with this statement since we have that:

$$\frac{\partial f_0(\mathbf J)}{\partial t}=-\left<[ f_1,H_1]\right>$$
here $f_1$ is the perturbed distribution. Although this is a slow variation it is non-zero and means (in my opinon) that $f_0$ should also depend on time $f_0(\mathbf{J}, t)$. But this then is not a steady state solution and as such violates the Jeans theorem meaning, as far as I can tell, there is no reason why $f_0$ can't also depend on the angles $\boldsymbol\theta$. Thus I think we should have $f_0(\mathbf{J},\boldsymbol\theta,t)$.

Question: What am I missing which makes $f_0(\mathbf{J})$ valid?

Comment: Isn't it typical to assume angular symmetry?

Comment: @KyleKanos no sorry, bold face doesn't seem to work on Greek letters, $\theta$  should be a vector and corresponds to the angle variables with corresponding angle coordinates. The statement seems to hold for the general case.

Comment: `\boldsymbol\theta` works just fine. Not sure why there's 2 angles to worry about (assuming $\boldsymbol{\theta}=\{\theta,\,\phi\}$?), nor do I see why angular symmetry wouldn't hold.

Comment: @KyleKanos Thanks I will edit this in. I am working in action-angle variables so $ \boldsymbol\theta=\frac{\partial S}{\partial \mathbf{J}}$ where $S$ is the generating function - in general we have 3 angles to worry about. I don't think angular symmetry is a required assumption e.g. we could have spiral arms. Also the perturbed distribution function $f_1$ would violate this.

Comment: I have found this arxiv paper which seems to at least try to explain it: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.1475.pdf

Comment: Is the following https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/279879/59023 along the lines of what you were thinking about?  Namely, rewriting the distribution function in terms of the invariants of motion?